# r-project SixSigma ss.rr gives Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length

Tags: r

I have below data.frame

```
> str(luc)
'data.frame':   19 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ driver  : Factor w/ 16 levels "nr #1","nr #10",..: 1 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 2 ...
 $ position: Factor w/ 16 levels "pos #1","pos #10",..: 1 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 2 ...
 $ ate     : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ i2      : num  0.00656 0.00676 0.00679 0.00681 0.00666 0.00657 0.00674 0.00676 0.00682 0.00684 ...
```

```
> luc
   driver position ate      i2
1   nr #1   pos #1   2 0.00656
2   nr #2   pos #2   2 0.00676
3   nr #3   pos #3   2 0.00679
4   nr #4   pos #4   2 0.00681
5   nr #5   pos #5   2 0.00666
6   nr #6   pos #6   2 0.00657
7   nr #7   pos #7   2 0.00674
8   nr #8   pos #8   2 0.00676
9   nr #9   pos #9   2 0.00682
10 nr #10  pos #10   1 0.00684
11 nr #11  pos #11   2 0.00671
12 nr #12  pos #12   2 0.00673
13 nr #13  pos #13   2 0.00660
14 nr #14  pos #14   2 0.00672
15 nr #15  pos #15   2 0.00673
16 nr #16  pos #16   2 0.00654
17  nr #7   pos #1   2 0.00678
18  nr #3   pos #2   2 0.00680
19  nr #1   pos #3   2 0.00658
```

which is extremely close to **ss.data.rr** provided by the SixSigma package.

Calling ss.rr with ss.data.rr works but what ever I try I always get below error when using luc:

```
> ss.rr(var=i2, appr=driver, part=ate, data=luc)
Error in ``row.names<-.data.frame``(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length
```

How to get rid of it?

Full code below; I create data.frame(luc) from much larger dataset.

```
library("SixSigma")

luc <- subset(cf, cf$CntrlVal == 85)
luc <- data.frame(cbind(luc$DriverNumber, luc$Position, luc$ATE, luc$I2))
colnames(luc)<-c("driver", "position", "ate", "i2")

luc$position <- as.factor(paste0("pos #", luc$position))
luc$driver<- as.factor(paste0("nr #", luc$driver))
luc[10, c("ate")] <- 1
luc<-luc[-c(20:48), ]

ss.rr(var=i2, appr=driver, part=ate, data=luc)

ss.rr(var=i2, appr=driver, part=position, data=luc)
```

Comment: Post complete code including any necessary `library()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Gage R&R needs repeated measures in order to assess the Measurement System. Apparently, the data set contains only one observation for each combination of factors (if any). For example, the ss.data.rr data.frame has 3 measurements of each prototype for each operator:

```
table(ss.data.rr$prototype, ss.data.rr$operator)

          op #1 op #2 op #3
  prot #1     3     3     3
  prot #2     3     3     3
  prot #3     3     3     3
```

The error is due to the fact that there is not a "Residuals" row in the anova table (Repeatibility component of variation). I will code an informative error in the next version of `SixSigma`.

Comment: Many Thanks Emilio, I obviously need to perform another measurement.

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to output only the tables without the charts in ss.rr? Thanks

Comment: Now yes, but you have to install de develop version from GitHub: 
devtools::install_github("emilopezcano/SixSigma", "develop")
Now ss.rr accepts a "print_plot" argument, if FALSE plots are ommited.